# SQL Server - filter specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select rows where the TYPE 'f' is selected over TYPE 'i' for the same Me (Metric) if the Type 'f' exists.

Example

from:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Me ║  VAL ║  TYPE ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    0 ║     f ║
║  1 ║    1 ║     i ║
║  2 ║    1 ║     i ║
║  2 ║    0 ║     f ║
║  3 ║    1 ║     i ║
║  4 ║    0 ║     i ║
║  5 ║    0 ║     i ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

get:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Me ║  BIT ║  TYPE ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║    0 ║     f ║
║  2 ║    1 ║     f ║
║  3 ║    1 ║     i ║
║  4 ║    0 ║     i ║
║  5 ║    0 ║     i ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 6):

The statement below uses `ROW_NUMBER()` which is a ranking function that generates sequential number. The number is generated for every `Me` and sorted by `Type`. This uses `CASE` assuming that there are other values of `TYPE` in the table.

```
SELECT  Me, Val, Type
        FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Me, Val, Type,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Me
                                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN Type = 'f' 
                                                    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
            FROM    tableName
        ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7505/2)

Comment: Yeah, I like this one better... it takes into account values that might come before 'f'.  + 1